# Proving Conditional Probability Statement

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

**Question:** Let $(\Omega, \mathscr F, \mathbb P)$ be a probability space. Prove or disprove that $P(A|B \cup C) = P(A|B) + P(A|C) ~~~\forall~~ A,B,C~ \in \mathscr F$ where $B \cap C = \emptyset$.

**Attempt**: Starting of with the LHS:

$$
P(A|B \cup C) = \frac{P(AB \cup AC)}{P(B \cup C)}\\
=\frac{P(AB) + P(AC) - P(ABC)}{P(B)+P(C)}\\
=\frac{P(AB)+P(AC)}{P(B)+P(C)}
$$
Then, expanding the RHS:
$$
P(A|B) + P(A|C) = \frac{P(AB)}{P(B)} + \frac{P(AC)}{P(C)}\\
=\frac{P(C)P(AB)+P(B)P(AC)}{P(B)P(C)}
$$

Comment: Sorry but in general, $$\frac{u}v+\frac{w}z\ne\frac{zu+vw}{v+z}.$$

Comment: @Did woops, think i was eager to see a connection between the LHS and RHS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A=\Omega$ and $C=B^c$. Then, if the relationship is true, we have
$$
1=P(\Omega\vert\Omega)=P(\Omega\vert B)+P(\Omega\vert B^c)=2.
$$